# How to make this query possible?

Tags: php, sql-server

Currently I need to find `nDays` when we only know the `character id`.

`nDays` can be found by `Account ID` but we only know the `Character ID`, so we must find first `AccountID` by matching the `CharacterID` and after that `nDays`.

TABLE: `PREMIUM_SERVICE` `(nDays,strAccountID)`

TABLE: `ACCOUNT_CHAR` `(strAccountID,CharID1,CharID2,CharID3)`

So, we need to match the character id from table ACCOUNT_CHAR and use this AccountID that we found for nDays from PREMIUM_SERVICE to see the days for this specific account id.

I am really trying to find and structure the exact query but failed so many times. Could you please show me how we can achieve this ?
I use MSSQL Server 2005

Kind Regards.

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join in your query

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: Okay, but how this will be possible to search for the Account ID from CharID1,CharID2 or CharID3 ? Since we can only have 1 character and we must search from these 3 to match the account id. Could you please help me out how this should be structured? I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT PS.CharID1, PS.CharID2, PS.CharID3, SUM(nDays) NumberOfDays
FROM ACCOUNT_CHAR AC LEFT JOIN PREMIUM_SERVICE PS
ON AC.strAccountID = PS.strAccountID
GROUP BY PS.CharID1, PS.CharID2, PS.CharID3
```

Comment: Thanks but Its not what I am looking for. I need to find strAccountID in ACCOUNT_CHAR by providing only one character id which should match somewhere in ACCOUNT_CHAR to find the strAccountID and use it in PREMIUM_SERVICE to see if there are any nDays left.

Comment: Your question is misleading and not clear what you are looking for please restate your question and show a desired result set what you would like to get from this query ??

Comment: I can provide only character id and I need to find out if it match in ACCOUNT_CHAR from any of the 3 characters and provide the accountid of it to PREMIUM_SERVICE so it can show me how many nDays left for this character id.